# I have an array within an object, and I'm trying to exclude values that contain a particular word in a string in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

For example: I have some arrays without the word "cheese" and some with "cheese" and others with "extra cheese."  $regex was a command I found that could search for particular word, so I could used that, I think, to exclude some values.

Here is one of my objects:

> {
>       "_id" : ObjectId("5ebf0cd0b14985ef2b48af46"),
>       "meat" : "chicken",
>       "cheese" : false,
>       "toppings" : [
>           "mac and cheese",
>           "biscuit"
>       ]
>   }

Cheese is included in "mac and cheese" and should not be returned.  I used "db.burger.find({}, {meat:1, toppings:1})" but it still returns the value "mac and cheese".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used SQL for a few years and would do something like where toppings NOT LIKE '%cheese%" and it would be excluded.  Mongo is something I just started looking into yesterday.

Comment: This is what solved my issue, if it helps anyone:  
db.burger.find( { toppings: { $not: /cheese/ } } )

Comment: Something like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/BDlw-AMPKbq ?